# Spring Mobile apps to be deployed in emulator

Tags: javascript, android, html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to develop an application based on Spring MVC for mobile device. Spring Mobile do provide such features to view our application in mobile browser. But how can I run/deploy the application in emulator since it's non-android based application? Also if can anybody tell me,  how can I test it in real device, It will be highly appreciated.

I'm using DHTMLX touch framework for javascript as well as HTML5.

Just a snippet of code below for spring mobile:

```Spring
@RequestMapping("/detect-device")
 public @ResponseBody String detectDevice(Device device)
 { String deviceType = "unknown"; 
if (device.isNormal())
 { deviceType = "normal"; } 
else if (device.isMobile())
 { deviceType = "mobile"; } 
else if (device.isTablet())
 { deviceType = "tablet"; }
```

Comment: Are you really planning to run a servlet container (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) on a mobile device? If you're creating a client application that Spring MVC is not the tool you're looking for.

Comment: Hii kryger ...the application is using Spring mobile to detect the device type           it will decide if it's user request is in mobile browser, tablet or desktop and will use REstful webservice . To deploy it i'm using Weblogic server .  Now wil it be possible to run and test the url in android emulator if i would like to test.

Comment: @kryger.......jst a snippet of code  below for spring mobile:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not actually developing a *mobile app* (which would be installed on the mobile device itself) but *a web page* that detects and supports mobile devices, you don't need an Android emulator.

What you *do* need is a browser that allows emulating a mobile client - Chrome has a neat Device Mode & Mobile Emulation which is a part of the standard Dev Tools. The Chrome Developer page has a [nice overview and a tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode); all you need to do to get started is to click the tiny smartphone icon in the developer tools panel.

Haven't investigated Firefox, but I'm assuming there is at least one plugin that offers similar functionality.